# Secure your flash/actionscript game?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, security

Is there any way I can secure my own flash game's source code?
Or even find a tricky way to hide it.. I was thinking of using something like this :
Put all my functions in an .as file in a folder like source/abasd/asdfas/code.as, and then import it from the game

```
  import source.*;
```

Would this actually work and people wouldn't see my code? Or there is no way of hiding it..

Answer (score 2):

You do not publish source as is, it's retrieved via Flash de-compilers. The best way you can reliably employ (which won't provide total protection anyway) is run an obfuscator against your SWF or source set. This way the SWF will be filled with lots of garbage which wouldn't break its normal work but will stand in the way of the hacker that'll try to retrieve the actual instruction set.

Comment: I see... i thought there would be a solution without having to use meaningless stuff to confuse the others..

Comment: To clarify on what Vesper noted; you do not post your .as files alongside your compiled SWF.  All of your code (either by using `include` or `import`) is stored inside your swf at compile time.  While most decompilers (such as SoThink) can reverse engineer your code, they are limited in what they can pull, especially if you add password protection in the publish settings "Protect from import."  If you want to really change it up, wrap your swf in an executable (such as MDM Zinc) and you should be fairly safe.

Answer (score 0):

A fast way to obfuscate your code is to embed the swf in another. No method is perfect but the idea is to make it harder so only some rare decompilers will be able to see anything.

```
[Embed(source="scene1.swf", symbol="scene1ID")]
private const SCENE1:Class;

private var scene1:MovieClip = new SCENE1() as MovieClip;
scene1.play();
```

Comment: I am not a flash developer, but wouldn't the person decompiling the swf see that you've embedded a different swf? Wouldn't it show up as a resource or something? Maybe your intention was only to deter the first wave of potential decompilers, in which case, carry on.